# Unity Arabic Text From JSON File

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, arabic-support

My problem is that when I get -for example- the word "سلام" from a JSON file, the output will be "????", but if I get -for example- "Peace" from the same JSON file, the output will be "Peace".

This the game that I am using (I get it from [this Unity tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/loading-game-data-json)):

```
private void LoadGameData()
{
    // Path.Combine combines strings into a file path
    // Application.StreamingAssets points to Assets/StreamingAssets in the Editor, and the StreamingAssets folder in a build
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, gameDataFileName);

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        // Read the json from the file into a string
        string dataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        // Pass the json to JsonUtility, and tell it to create a GameData object from it
        GameData loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameData>(dataAsJson);

        // Retrieve the allRoundData property of loadedData
        allRoundData = loadedData.al_asallRoundDataela;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Cannot load game data!");
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to a mismatch in the **Encoding**. Use the **ReadAllText** overload which allows you to specify the proper Encoding to use when reading the file.

The default overload will assume **UTF-8** unless it can detect **UTF-32.** Any other encoding will come through incorrectly.

I think the right code is:

```
var arabic = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
 File.ReadAllText(filePath,arabic);
```